# Swift 5 Result: XCTAssertEqual is ambiguous without more context

Tags: unit-testing, swift5

`XCTAssertEqual produces an error: Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context` when comparing two result values(see below):

```
let success = Result<String, Error>.success("Value")
let failure = Result<String, Error>.failure(NSError.createError("Error"))

XCTAssertEqual(success, failure)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `success` and `failure` you're trying to compare is not `Equatable`.

`Result<Success, Failure>` only conforms to `Equatable` when both `Success` and `Failure` conform to `Equatable`. From the definition of `Result`:

```
extension Result : Equatable where Success : Equatable, Failure : Equatable {}
```

Thus, you'll need to use a custom `Error` type that conforms to `Equatable` or use a different way to compare the two values by first extracting the success (or failure) value:

```
switch (a, b) {
case let (.success(x), .success(y)):
    XCTAssertEqual(x, y)
default:
    XCTFail()
}
```